POST URL 404 Not Found /api/
I want to gather data from a page when a certain function is called, then send the data to my database. I'm using Expressjs and Nodejs.
The function with the Fetch:
function saveShapeData() {
const shapesData = [];
$(".shape").each(function() {
  const shapeId = $(this).attr("id");
  const shapeData = {
    id: shapeId,
    imgElement: $(this).find("img").attr("src"), 
    items: $(this).data("info") ? $(this).data("info").items : [],
    css: $(this).attr("style")
  };
  shapesData.push(shapeData);
});
fetch("/api/shapes", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(shapesData),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})}

Router:
router.get("/shapes", loggedIn, (req, res) => {
if(req.user){
    console.log("saedfe " + req.user.shapes);
    res.sendFile("shapes.html", { root: "./public/" });
}
else{
    res.render("index", {status:"no", user: "nothing"});
}

})
Controller:
const db = require('../routes/db-config.js');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const shapes = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { shapesData } = req.body;
    if (!req.cookies.userRegistered) return next();
    try{
        const decoder = jwt.verify(req.cookies.userRegistered, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        db.query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?) WHERE id = ?', [shapesData, decoder.id], (err, result) => {
            if(err) return next();

            return next();
        })
    } catch (err){
        if(err) return next()
    }
}

module.exports = shapes;

I have register and login pages which work just fine with pretty much the same structured code, but this one returns the error:
POST http://localhost:5000/api/shapes/ 404 (Not Found)

My auth.js looks like this, with login and register pages being routed the same way:
const express = require('express');
const register = require('./register')
const login = require('./login')
const shapes = require('./shapes')

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", register)
router.post("/login", login)
router.post("/shapes", shapes)

module.exports = router;


You are trying to access the path /api/shapes, but you seem to have /shapes only.

The fetch on the register and login pages work the same somehow, where I fetch /api/register, while only having /register and those don't give errors.

The path is incorrect, you would want to set it like so router.post("/api/shapes", shapes)

in my index.js I have a line:
app.use("/api", require("./controllers/auth"));
This is why is didn't put api in front of the routing.

Actually, I might have figured out that what I'm trying doesn't make a lot of sense. What I actually want to do, is I have the shapesData array from the frontend, I want to access that from the backend so that I can post it to my database. The question is, how do I access that array from a different js file?

try to remove "api"
POST http://localhost:5000/api/shapes/
in what you showed, there is no such route

gives the same error except POST http://localhost:5000/shapes/

Was it at this door that you opened the route? show more of the code
